# SharePoint Online Search Subsite Disable Searching Document Content

Tags: search

For SharePoint Online, is it possible in a search results web part to exclude the contents within a document (i.e. pdf) in the results, and to only search metadata? Basically, I want it to search only on title. I understand as part of OOTB SharePoint, the contents of the documents are automatically included. I was just wondering if there is a way to turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question before, and think the answer is no.

If you know the metadata columns you might customize the web part's query to do an OR search on just the metadata columns. This is probably not the correct syntax...

```
Title:{Search Term} OR ProjectName:{Search Term} OR Description:{Search Term}
```

This works for just Title: Edit the Search Results web part, click Change Query, edit the query text.

[image]